# How can I create bash_profile and bashrc

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan

I want to create some alias, so I go to `~/` folder and there is no `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

[image: ls -a ~/]

I have been looking for some info and I learn that `.bash_profile` is only read when bash launch an interactive login shell (default type of terminal in OS X) and `.bashrc` is only read when bash launch an interactive non-login shell. But I don't find how to create `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` for my user. How can I do it?

After @klanomath answer:

[image]

Comment: You may want to create a `.bashrc` that contains:-
`[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile` so that all shells will share the same settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
touch ~/.bashrc
```

To edit the file(s) use:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Instead of nano you can use any decent text editor (e.g. BBEdit, [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)).

To immediately enable any changes in the file .bash_profile use `source`:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I already try that but didn't work :( 
Please, look the new photo that I attach to the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I try `source  ~/.bash_profile` …didn't work.

Comment: @raaowx the correct expression is `alias lsa='ls -a | egrep "\.[a-zA-Z0-9]"'`instead of `alias lsa='ls -a | egrep '\.[a-zA-Z0-9]'`! The inner `'` are wrong and you are missing one finishing `'`