# How do I fix a syntax error in .bash_profile

Tags: terminal, bash

I was installing ruby on rails along with homebrew the other day and was following a step by step list of what to do. I now have this bash syntax error every time I enter the terminal:

```
-bash: /Users/briggsmcknight/.bash_profile: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `source'
-bash: /Users/briggsmcknight/.bash_profile: line 6: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/briggsmcknight/.bash_profile'
```

Could I get a small step by step breakdown of what I should do to fix this?
I believe the syntax error is by "fi" or "source", but do I just retype it again or what?

Comment: Can You paste first 7 lines of your `.bash_profile` file?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek He can't as he can't get a command line prompt

Comment: @BriggsMcnight do you end up with a prompt in the terminal or does the shell exit?

Comment: He can open it via TextEdit.app (If file is hidden, there's a shortcut to see it Open File dialog: CMD+SHIFT+.  <dot> )

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I had forgotten the key shortcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest step might be to move the hidden file to your desktop and [start over](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99835/how-to-create-bash-profile-and-profile) making [that file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219202/how-can-i-create-bash-profile-and-bashrc).

If you're OK editing the file - perhaps using nano - you can delete the line 6 or comment it out by putting a # before the first character on that line and saving the file.

```
/usr/sbin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

To just start over and get a working terminal:

```
/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/Desktop/bash_profile.txt
```

Comment: How do you move the file? It is probably hidden and so not visible in Finder

Comment: @Mark yup - that's why the mv command to remove the leading . ; - ) Also - you still get a prompt when there's an error in the startup shells. Just type the letters above (`mv` is best to do first if you're not sure if you can edit it in shape) and then open a new terminal to test your work.

Comment: Awesome it worked! Much appreciated bmike.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file with a GUI program e.g. TextEdit

Open TextEdit and select the home directory. .bash_profile is hidden so instead of a simple selection then you might have to hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to show .bash_profile When saving delete the .txt ending TextEdit adds or alter TextEdits's preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file with a GUI app like TextEdit or TextWrangler - I recommend the latter.

Open the invisible file *.bash_profile* in your home folder either with TextEdit by hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or with TextWrangler by checking the button "Show hidden items" in the open dialog.

Remove all `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/briggsmcknight/.bash_profile` related lines and only leave `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` and your other mods in the file.

Save the file as .bash_profile (without any suffix like txt or rtf).

Relaunch Terminal.

---

You mustn't source .bash_profile in the file .bash_profile itself (without a proper if/then/else statement) because you will either get an error or a loop.