# Unknown error message in Terminal .bash_profile

Tags: terminal, mac, error

-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export:`0de946b3adfc5de6336ff06ca740ffbeba68f055323038a179def14f63ee3b1b7aa0b50bdd8a7b7578d8c19f1a5e62fff0047843b252e551426e2c0a5f49ee88': not a valid identifier

I was following a guide to install postgres , and i added a PATH to .bash_profile .Then i deleted it and now i am facing this error every time i open the terminal.

**This is my bash profile**

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export SECRET_KEY_BASE = 0de946b3adfc5de6336ff06ca740ffbeba68f055323038a179def14f63ee3b1b7aa0b50bdd8a7b7578d8c19f1a5e62fff0047843b252e551426e2c0a5f49ee88
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `.bash_profile` to your question by [editing the original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/324496/edit)

Comment: Your .bash_profile probably contains a line similar to `export y = x...` (i.e. a space or some spaces around the `=`). Remove the space(s)!

Comment: Is this basically a "how do I fix my script" which is asked and answered in a couple other threads? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264073/how-do-i-fix-a-syntax-error-in-bash-profile

Comment: `export SECRET_KEY_BASE = 0de946...`> `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=0de946...`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export a variable, the variable name, the equal sign and the value of the variable mustn't be separated by spaces! Especially the equal sign is no valid variable name and surrounded by spaces it's interpreted as such resulting in the *"=': not a valid identifier"* error message.

So change the line

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE = 0de946b3adfc5de6336ff06ca740ffbeba68f055323038a179def14f63ee3b1b7aa0b50bdd8a7b7578d8c19f1a5e62fff0047843b252e551426e2c0a5f49ee88
```

to

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=0de946b3adfc5de6336ff06ca740ffbeba68f055323038a179def14f63ee3b1b7aa0b50bdd8a7b7578d8c19f1a5e62fff0047843b252e551426e2c0a5f49ee88
```

and either re-source .bash_profile or close your current Terminal window and open a new one to get rid of the error.